# What is the Objective-C equivalent to a .Net delegate?

Tags: .net, objective-c, kobold2d

In .Net when I have an object that has an event I can register to handle that event via a delegate:

```
void Test()
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Click  += new EventHandler(OnClick);
}
void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    text1.Text = "The Button Was Clicked";
}
```

How do I do this sort of thing in Objective-C?  Specifically I'm trying to handle the ccTouchEnded of a SneakyButton.  I thought it would be something like this:

```
SneakyButton* mybutton = [SneakyButton button];
[mybutton ccTouchEnded:self.onButtonDown];

- (void)onButtonDown:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CCLOG(@"The Button Was Clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocoa and CocoaTouch often uses "Target/Action".

- *Target:* an objc object. the target is what gets messaged.
- *Action:* a selector. the action is the selector to message the target with.

In that sense, the *action* is the equivalent.

When the target/action is performed, it would take this *general* form:

```
[target performSelector:action withObject:someParameter];
```

of course, the parameter list will vary in the real world.

The `UIControl` class is quite small - read it for more info on the subject. It will give you a good idea of a control's target/action support and the interfaces you'll use for handling these events. `NSControl` is the Cocoa counterpart, but that's a much larger class - it defines much more than Target/Action interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
[mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonDown:withEvent:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Note that the first argument to `onButtonDown:withEvent:` will be the button object, not the touch object.

You can read more about the target/action pattern in the [*Cocoa Fundamentals Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW44).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it might be something like this:

```
[mybutton ccTouchEnded:self.onButtonDown];
```

and

```
(void)myButtonClick:(id)sender {
    mylabel.text = @"The Button Was Clicked";
}
```

This link might help: http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=13